# sscanf - read hex values won't work with comma

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to skip string and parse two values as in code below:

```cpp
int main()
{
    char format[] = "%*s HEX_DATA:%04x, NEGATIVE_VAL:%d";
    char str[] = "text_to_be_skipped, HEX_DATA:d800, NEGATIVE_VAL:-20";

    uint16_t hex_data = 0;
    int8_t neg_val = 0;

    int status = sscanf(str, format, &hex_data, &neg_val);

    printf("Status: %d, HEX_DATA: %04x, NEGATIVE_VAL: %d", status, hex_data, neg_val);

    return 0;
}
```

It returns the following output:

```
Status: 2, HEX_DATA: ffff, NEGATIVE_VAL: -20
```

The hex value is wrong. When `,` in `format[]` is removed then output is as follows:

```
Status: 1, HEX_DATA: d800, NEGATIVE_VAL: 0
```

Now `hex_data` value is parsed correctly but `neg_val` is not parsed. How to parse them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `%*s`, you should instead use `%*[^,],` to ignore all characters (including whitespace) up to, and including, the first comma before `HEX_DATA`.

Also, `%04x` needs an `(un)signed int` to write to, not a `uint16_t` (also, the leading `0` is not needed). And `%d` needs a `(signed) int` to write to, not a `int8_t`.  Use the `h` and `hh` type modifiers to write to smaller types, respectively.

See [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more details.

Try this instead:

```c
int main()
{
    char format[] = "%*[^,], HEX_DATA:%4hx, NEGATIVE_VAL:%hhd";
    char str[] = "text_to_be_skipped, HEX_DATA:d800, NEGATIVE_VAL:-20";

    uint16_t hex_data = 0;
    int8_t neg_val = 0;

    int status = sscanf(str, format, &hex_data, &neg_val);

    printf("Status: %d, HEX_DATA: %04x, NEGATIVE_VAL: %d", status, hex_data, neg_val);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Status: 2, HEX_DATA: d800, NEGATIVE_VAL: -20
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/tDsgVs)

**UPDATE**: Or better, use the `SCNd8`, `SCNx16`, `PRId8`, and `PRIx16` format helper macros from `<inttypes.h>`, eg:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    char format[] = "%*[^,], HEX_DATA:%4" SCNx16 ", NEGATIVE_VAL:%" SCNd8;
    char str[] = "text_to_be_skipped, HEX_DATA:d800, NEGATIVE_VAL:-20";

    uint16_t hex_data = 0;
    int8_t neg_val = 0;

    int status = sscanf(str, format, &hex_data, &neg_val);

    printf("Status: %d, HEX_DATA: %04" PRIx16 ", NEGATIVE_VAL: %" PRId8, status, hex_data, neg_val);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Status: 2, HEX_DATA: d800, NEGATIVE_VAL: -20
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/1CQnYg)

Comment: The comma is a rad-herring -- it has nothing to do with the problem.  You can change the scanf spec to use `%*[^,]` instead of `%*s`, but it really has nothing to do with the question or the problem.

Comment: @ChrisDodd "*The comma is a rad-herring*" - that depends on whether `text_to_be_skipped` contains whitespace or not. Obviously in the example given, it doesn't, but we clearly don't know the *real* content of `text_to_be_skipped` in the OP's production code. `%*s` will stop parsing if it encounters whitespace before a comma (https://ideone.com/g8pCvo), whereas `%*[^,],` will stop parsing only when it encounters a comma (https://ideone.com/iTtw98). And since there is clearly a comma before `HEX_DATA`, I would opt for the latter to be safe.

Comment: I would say its as likely to contain a comma (or not end with a comma) as it is to contain a space -- anything more complex than the example could be a problem, and really has nothing to do with the problem of sscanf returning apparent success (2) with invalid data in the variables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your data types don't match your format string -- `x` is for reading an unsigned int, not a uint16_t, and `d` is for an int, not an int8_t.  Try

```
char format[] = "%*s HEX_DATA:%04"SCNx16", NEGATIVE_VAL:%"SCNd8;
```

Comment: Also change the `%04` to `%4`, the `0` is useless and confusing

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes: true it has no effect, but it is not harmful -- it has no effect